# Task of getline

Tags: c++, string, iostream

The `getline` function can takes three parameters. First of them is the object `cin`. Second of them is the object defined with the class `string`. Third of them is delimiter character.

1. If the delimiter character is not found, what happens?
2. For example, I chose character `'t'` for delimiter.Then, the user entered `"Jonathan"`. Does `"han"` remain in buffer or `"han\n"` remain in buffer? (I read that `getline` deletes newline in buffer in every time although delimiter is not newline character but I do not ensure this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented in [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

> 2) Extracts characters from input and appends them to str until one of the following occurs (checked in the order listed)
>   a) end-of-file condition on input, in which case, getline sets eofbit.
>   b) the next available input character is delim, as tested by Traits::eq(c, delim), in which case the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to str.

In the case of `std::getline(std::cin, str, 't');`, this means `str` will contain `Jona`, `t` will be extracted and discarded, keeping `han\n` in the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

string x;
char y;

getline(cin, x, 'n');

cin >> y;

return 0;

}
```

If the user enters "John", then "\n" remains in buffer.Finally, the user cannot enter a character for y. However, the user can enter a character for y. where does newline go ?